# Setting expire headers for static content with nginx

Tags: nginx, caching

I'm using Nginx in front of Glassfish (java application server) to serve my static content. I'm using following setting to set the expire headers

```
location /javax.faces.resource/images/ {
                proxy_pass http://xx.xxx.xx:8080/javax.faces.resource/images/;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                expires         365d;
                add_header      Pragma public;
                add_header      Cache-Control "public";
        }
```

I have also CSS and JS files inside `/javax.faces.resource/` and want to set another expire header. How can I achieve this without breaking the setting for images? 
 
Another question: I noticed that sometimes there is many `Cache-Control` entries in Response header. 
 Is there a possibility to reset the properties instead of using `add_header`? 
 Thanks 
**EDITED**

```
server {
     listen          xx.x.yy.xxx:80;
     server_name     mydomain.com www.mydomain.com ;

     rewrite ^/(.*) https://www.$server_name/$1 permanent;
}
server {
        listen          xx.x.yy.xxx:443; ## listen for ipv4
        server_name     www.mydomain.com;
        ssl on;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/www.mydomain.com.2018.pem;
        # Path to an SSL certificate;

        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/www.mydomain.com.2018.key;
        # Path to the key for the SSL certificate;


        client_max_body_size    20M;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.access.log upstreamlog;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/mydomain.com.error.log;
        rewrite_log on;


        location / {
                proxy_pass http://xx.x.yy.xxx:8080;


                proxy_set_header        Host                    $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header        HTTPS "on";

        }

        location /nginx_status {
                stub_status on;
                access_log   off;
        #       allow 1.1.1.1;
        #        deny all;
        }

        location /images/ {
                proxy_pass http://xx.x.yy.xxx:8080/images/;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                expires         365d;
                add_header      Pragma public;
                add_header      Cache-Control "public";

                #add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                #add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        } 

        location /resources/desktop/images/ {
                proxy_pass http://xx.x.yy.xxx:8080/resources/desktop/images/;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                expires         365d;
                add_header      Pragma public;
                add_header      Cache-Control "public";

                #add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;
                #add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
        }

        location /javax.faces.resource/images/ {
                proxy_pass http://xx.x.yy.xxx:8080/javax.faces.resource/images/;
                proxy_set_header        Host            $http_host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
                expires         365d;
                add_header      Pragma public;
                add_header      Cache-Control "public";
        }
}
```

Comment: Look at my recent answer at [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/943946/nginx-proxy-pass-setup-fails-when-adding-a-location-for-expiring-file-types/943954#943954).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'm not really sure how it should be done in my case. Cause it's different. I've a proxy_pass etc. Could you post an answer? so I can accept it.

Comment: There are a different ways to do it, can you post your full `server` block of your config so I can choose the best way?

Comment: I added my full config block.

Comment: I also tried the `map` approach described in your link. Each time I inserted `expires  $expires;` restarting nginx failed.

Comment: OMG. You said: "I'm using Nginx in front of Glassfish (java application server) to serve my static content." So **why** are you bypassing to your backend all requests including the requests for static content? With this config you achieved nothing but an extra load on your server!

Comment: What nginx version do you have?

Comment: Using nginx in front of an application server is very common and has many advantages like serving SSL and using many pageSpeed filters. Using nginx for permanent Redirects with Nginx is much much easier than with a java application server.

Comment: On my server is version 1.6.2 running.

Comment: That's right, but with your config you didn't use it's main advantage - serving static content, you just pass all the requests to your backend. You didn't even configure you `root`! And I don't know what URLs should be passed to your backend and what should be not. Here is the [example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/javaservers/) for Jetty java app server, which passed to backend all `/.../*.do`, `/.../*.jsp` and `/.../servlets/...` URLs, but I don't know is it appropriate for your case.

Comment: If you can formulate rules which URLs for sure must be processed by your backend, we can continue. BTW, can you update your nginx to a newer version? 1.6.x are known to have problems with regular expressions whithin the `map` directives.

Comment: The config has been set by the server provider. I added by my self only the location part serving static content. Which is working.  Updating nginx on a production server is not easy! It's gonna take to find right time.  I the mean time I found a way to set the expire value directly in my web application.